# Locked relationships in Gephi

Tags: gephi

I've imported nodes with edges in gephi and now I'm trying to get partitions  containing four nodes , connected only to each-other(multiple connections are  allowed),  creating rectangle.

Comment: So you want to find all partitions `(u,v,x,y)` where you are having paths `u->v->x->y` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeap you got the idea, that's exactly what I'm looking for .

Comment: I think this might be to complicated to do in Gephi. Perhaps you can use the scripting console to write some Python code that does that or otherwise export the graph and process it in your favorite language